# Updating single list item in Objective C

Tags: sharepoint-online, json

I am trying to update a single list item in SharePoint from an iPhone App.  Here is the code.  If I change the X-HTTP Method to DELETE the item is deleted, so I know my Digest Value and authentication work.  Can someone see why my TaskOutcome field will not update?  Is my JSON string wrong?  Please help.  **Note even if I want to change a simple field like "title" it will not respond to the code.  I got the type value from here...https:///_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Workflow%20Tasks')/listItemEntityTypeFullName returns SP.Data.WorkflowTasksItem as type value.

```
   //Single field value I want to change
NSString *value =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"_metadata\":{\"Type\":\"SP.Data.WorkflowTasksItem\"},\"TaskOutcome\":\"Approved\"}"];

NSData *work = [value dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSLog(@"This is the data %@",value);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:work];
[request setValue:@"application/json;odata=verbose" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json;odata=verbose" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"MERGE" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-HTTP-Method"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[work length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:formDigestValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-RequestDigest"];
[request setValue:@"*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"IF-Match"];


NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
self.connection = connection;

[connection start];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is more to the workflow task than just approving it.

```
PercentComplete: 1
Status: 'Approved'
WorkflowOutcome : "Approved"
```

and your `SP.Data.WorkflowTasksItem` probably should be changed to:
 `SP.Data.Workflow_x0020_TasksListItem`

Answer (score 0):

Metadata needs two underscores before the word:

_metadata **wrong

__metadata **right